# Please help me with JFrame and BorderLayout in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, jlist

Can someone tell me why my JList and JLabel are not automatically resizing to fill up the entire screen? Also why doesn't by JButton automatically resize? Thanks a ton

```
public class testing extends JFrame {

    private String[] testArray = {"apple", "banana", "cat"};
    private JPanel firstLayer = new JPanel();
    private JPanel secondLayerLeft = new JPanel();
    private JPanel secondLayerRight = new JPanel();
    private JList<String> leftText = new JList<String>();
    private JLabel rightOutput = new JLabel();
    private JButton button = new JButton("test button");

    public testing(){
        firstLayer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        firstLayer.add(secondLayerLeft, BorderLayout.WEST);
        firstLayer.add(secondLayerRight, BorderLayout.EAST);
        firstLayer.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        secondLayerLeft.add(leftText);
        leftText.setListData(testArray);
        secondLayerRight.add(rightOutput);
        rightOutput.setText("testing 12345");


        secondLayerLeft.setBorder(new EtchedBorder());
        secondLayerRight.setBorder(new EtchedBorder());

        this.add(firstLayer);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testing gui = new testing();
        gui.setSize(700, 800);
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: How would I go about making a JList and JLabel stretch to fill the entire screen and resize automatically?

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic feature of `BorderLayout`.  Only the `CENTER` position is resized automatically.  The only way any of border components can change size is if, they in fact, change size (`getPreferredSize` changes before the next layout is carried out)

Answer (score 1):

Your left and right panels are exactly the correct size to hold the preferred sizes of the JPanels they contain.  Your button occupies the entire south portion of the border layout, just as it ought, and resizes beautifully.  If you want something to stretch to the whole window, put it in the center.

Comment: How would I go about making a JList and JLabel stretch to fill the entire screen and resize automatically?

Comment: @user2238529 Personally, I'd use a different layout.  Depending on the needs, I'd probably use a `GridBagLayout`

Comment: And it depends on what you mean.  Do you want them to be the same size as each other, and stretch so that they're always the same size as each other? In both dimensions?  I think it takes many people by surprise just how complicated it is to describe a UI layout FULLY, so that someone else knows what it is they want.  Imagine your screen the way you want it, then how it is if stretched horizontally, vertically, and both.  That will get the stretching parts, anyway.  At least you don't have one of these stacked multi-row multi-column monstrosities that you're trying to describe in 20 words.